# Sending JSON from AJAX to Controller Class

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to send JSON to a class and it seems straightforward but for some reason it always shows up as null? Here's the situation:

AjaxCall is triggered by a change event. The url is correct, type is set to POST, and data is already converted with JSON.stringify() and logs as {"country":"Canada"}

```
function AjaxCall(u, d, t){
    console.log(d);
    return $.ajax({
        url: u,
        type: t ? t : 'GET',
        data: d,                
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

The class is triggered, but the country string is always null.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetProv(string country)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

What am I missing?!

**Edit:**
My Model:

```
public class country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should get country from body not from route or query string, create a that has a country property and in action use ``[FromBody]``.

Comment: Hi @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, not sure I understand, are you saying I should reference the model? Something like:  `public JsonResult GetProv([FromBody] Country countrySelected)`

Comment: I guess I did understand as I am bringing back results now. Thank you for you assistance!